# Generating multiple tasks within Airflow DAG to be processed individually

Tags: airflow

There are parts of my DAG that generate lists which I cannot break up into individual tasks to be processed individually downstream.

Here's a pseudo example:

```
def push(**kwargs):
    # """Pushes an XCom without a specific target"""
    for n in range(10):
        kwargs['ti'].xcom_push(key=f'vals', value=n)

def puller(**kwargs):
    ti = kwargs['ti']
    v1 = ti.xcom_pull(key='vals', task_ids='push')
    print(v1)

push = python_operator.PythonOperator(
    task_id='push',
    python_callable=push,
    provide_context=True
)

puller = python_operator.PythonOperator(
    task_id='puller',
    python_callable=puller,
    provide_context=True
)
```

It appears the xcom_push only uses the last value, not generates a list. Therefore, I'd have to load the values in push into a list then use a for loop in the pull to process each item individually.

I'm completely fine doing that but it seems counter-intuitive for doing batch jobs.

How would I have the puller pull one of the 10 tasks generated by push?

Answer (score 4):

Between DAG runs, you shouldn't be changing the structure of the DAG, so your puller is either one task, meant to pull all the values, or 10 tasks each meant to pull one of the values.

Here's how you'd push all 10 values with xcom:

```
def push(**kwargs):
    # """Pushes an XCom without a specific target"""
    final_output = []
    for n in range(10):
        # doing work
        final_output.append(n)
    kwargs['ti'].xcom_push(key=f'vals', value=final_output)

push = python_operator.PythonOperator(
    task_id='push',
    python_callable=push,
    provide_context=True
)
```

And then you can either pull all 10 of them like this

```
def puller(**kwargs):
    ti = kwargs['ti']
    v1 = ti.xcom_pull(key='vals', task_ids='push')
    print(v1)  # [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

puller = python_operator.PythonOperator(
    task_id='puller',
    python_callable=puller,
    provide_context=True
)
```

Or one value for each of ten tasks:

```
def puller(index=0, **kwargs):
    ti = kwargs['ti']
    v1 = ti.xcom_pull(key='vals', task_ids='push')[index]
    print(v1)

ten_ops = [python_operator.PythonOperator(
        task_id=f'puller_{n}',
        python_callable=puller,
        provide_context=True,
        op_kwargs={'index': n},
    ) for n in range(10)]
```

I hope that helps, unless I misunderstood the question.

Comment: You nailed it. Thank you. I suspected the functionality I  am looking for is not explicit or desired in Airflow (probably more Spark). Are there issues with doing your second example?

Comment: @ethanenglish The only issues would be that that range, the number of operators in the dag, should not be dynamic or changing between scheduled runs. OTHERWISE you should instead consider that a single operator should trigger multiple runs of another unscheduled DAG a dynamic number of times to do the variable amounts of processing.

Comment: Gotcha. Do you know of a good example of a DAG triggering another DAG? I think it might be this: https://airflow.apache.org/code.html?highlight=triggerdagrun#airflow.operators.dagrun_operator.TriggerDagRunOperator but not sure how it'd be implemented.

Comment: @ethanenglish You might like to refer to https://github.com/apache/airflow/tree/master/airflow/example_dags trigger controller and trigger target dags.

Comment: I was just implementing that :) My Pub/Sub sensor was triggering the entire DAG -- even when there were no messages -- so I'll separate the sensor from the DAG that processes those messages. The trigger will have a python_callable that pulls from the Pub/Sub queue and if there is a message, it'll trigger the processing DAG. Thanks for your help here. I really appreciate it.

Comment: @ethanenglish glad to have helped; you're aware that you can also get people interactively on the apache-airflow.slack.com?

Comment: you're blowin my mind! Thanks. I just figured out how to trigger a Dag from a PubSub trigger :) I'm really, really digging Airflow.